# django-social-auth login always showing twitter signin page

Tags: django

I'm using [django-social-auth](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html) for twitter. The first time a user has to authorize the application on twitter, but on the second login twitter **should** just redirect the user back without asking to authorize the application again.

For me it always asks to authorize the app even if I have already authorize the application before. I get logged on as normal but its not how it should work. Why?

The django-social-auth demo does not do this. What have I done different?

Have I missed something here to get this behavior? maybe a pipe that saves something as a cookie?

**Link**

```
<a href="{% url 'socialauth_begin' "twitter" %}" class="btn_1">Login with Twitter</a>
```

**pipes**

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.social_auth_user',
    #'social_auth.backends.pipeline.associate.associate_by_email',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.userena.create_profile',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.userena.create_account',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.associate_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.load_extra_data',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.update_user_details'
)
```

Comment: Maybe your problem isn't in your code, but in your Twitter app settings. Make sure you have "Allow this application to be used to Sign in with Twitter" checked on your settings.

Comment: o wow that was it!!! please answer I'll select as correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your problem isn't in your code, but in your Twitter app settings. Make sure you have "Allow this application to be used to Sign in with Twitter" checked on your settings